# Measure of measurable sets as supremum of compacts

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable set. Show that $$ |E|=\sup\{m(K): K \subset E, K \space \text{compact}\}$$

I've already proved that for $E$ measurable set, $|E|=\inf\{m(G): E\subset G, G \space \text{open}\}$, I've also shown that $E=H \cup N$, where $H$ is $F_{\sigma}$ and $N$ is a null set. I couldn't relate these two properties with the original statement. Any help on how could I show the statement would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have the $H$ that is a union of countably many closed sets, then intersect them with a sequence (bounded) balls of increasing sizes that tend to infinity.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I got it: Since $E$ is measurable, then $E=H \cup N$ and $|H|=|E|$. For arbitrary $n$, consider $B(0,n)$, then $|B(0,n) \cap H| \leq |H|$ and (how can I justify this?) $|B(0,n) \cap H|  \to |H|$, then $\sup |B(0,n) \cap H|=|H|=|E|$.